# Mutex vs Event in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, events, mutex

can somebody please explain what is the difference if I do

```
mutex = createMutex
waitForSingleObject
Release(mutex)
```

and

```
event = createEvent
waitForSingleObject
Release(event)
```

I'm so confused, can I use both versions for the synchronization? thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You use a mutex to ensure that only one thread of execution can be accessing something. For example, if you want to update a list that can potentially be used by multiple threads, you'd use a mutex:

```
acquire mutex
update list
release mutex
```

With a mutex, only one thread at a time can be executing the "update list".

You use a manual reset event if you want multiple threads to wait for something to happen before continuing. For example, you started multiple threads, but they're all paused waiting for some other event before they can continue. Once that event happens, all of the threads can start running.

The main thread would look like this:

```
create event, initial value false (not signaled)
start threads
do some other initialization
signal event
```

Each thread's code would be:

```
do thread initialization
wait for event to be signaled
do thread processing
```

Comment: what is an initial value of the mutex: signaled or not signaled?

Comment: @yeap: In almost all cases, including this one, you want to create the mutex so that it's initially not acquired.

Comment: One important difference is that a mutex can be locked repeatedly by the same thread (it's "recursive") whereas an event can be used to implement non-recursive locking.

Comment: And what if Event is fired when I wasn't waiting for it, but once I'm ready it isn't fired(e.g. init ready event)

Comment: @Johnny_D: If a manual reset event is set, it remains set until it's reset. So in your case the event is set, the other thread comes along and sees that it's set, and just continues--no waiting necessary. If you have further questions about how events work, post a question rather than commenting here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both can be used for synchronization but in different ways.

**Mutex** is a mutual exclusion object and can be acquired only by a single instance at a time. It is used to avoid the simultaneous use of a common resource, such as a global variable, by pieces of computer code

**Event** is an objet that can be explicitly set to a state by use of the SetEvent function.

Comment: what do You mean "of a tine"? can event be acquired by multiple instances? mutex also can be signaled if I do waitForSingleObject, am I wrong?

Comment: yes, both and in fact any synchronization object can be used in WaitForSingleObject/ WaitForMultipleObject. The difference is in his behavior.

Comment: an Event is not acquired like a mutex or critical section is acquired. An event can be signaled when an event has occurred.

Comment: what about multiple instances? can multiple instances be waiting for the some signal?